# Can a linear operator on a Banach space be both open and closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $P:X\to X$ be a bounded linear projection.

Since $P$ is bounded, $P$ is continuous.

Since $P$ is continuous, the Closed Graph Theorem says $\{(x,P(x))\,\mid\,x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times Y$.

Since $\{(x,P(x)\,\mid\,x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times Y$, $P(X)$ is closed in $Y$.

Since $P(X)$ is closed in $Y$, the Open Mapping Theorem says $P$ is open.

Hence $P$ is both open and closed.

Is this right or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: How does the open mapping theorem apply? Is $P$ surjective?

Comment: To apply the Open Mapping Theorem you need P to be onto.

Comment: Ah. It would seem that I am doing something stupid. P cannot be surjective unless it is the identity map.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that a non-surjective bounded linear projection is closed?

Comment: @copper.hat: How can P act as a surjective projection unless it is the identity? Won't there always be points in the codomain $X$ that have no image under a projection?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the projection part. Will delete comment.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks for the clarification. I thought I was firing on all cylinders of stupid for a second!

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x) = 0$. Then $P(U) = \{0\}$ for all open $U$, hence it is not open.